# Is there a way that when I push data it doesn't show output the last line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, push

```
let row = warehouse_delivery_transaction.find(x => x.kerry_status_name === 'CCC')
    if (!row) {
      let item = warehouse_delivery_transaction.find(x => x.kerry_status_name === 'BBB')
      if (item) {
        warehouse_delivery_transaction.push({
          code: item.code,
          kerry_status_name: 'CCC',
          location: '',
          status_date: item.status_date
        })
      }
    }
```

Output before

```
1.AAA
2.BBB
3.DDD
```

Output After I push data

```
1.AAA
2.BBB
3.DDD
4.CCC
```

I want it to come out like this.

```
1.AAA
2.BBB
3.CCC
4.DDD
```

Comment: you are using push, which appends to the end, what you need to use is splice

Comment: If that's the case you can sort the array.

Comment: .sort ? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)

Answer (score 0):

Used [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to insert to the `warehouse_delivery_transaction.length-1` position

```js
let warehouse_delivery_transaction = [{
    code: 'aa',
    kerry_status_name: 'AAA',
    location: '',
    status_date: 'aa'
  },
  {
    code: 'bb',
    kerry_status_name: 'BBB',
    location: '',
    status_date: 'bb'
  }, {
    code: 'dd',
    kerry_status_name: 'DDD',
    location: '',
    status_date: 'dd'
  }
]

console.log('Before: ', warehouse_delivery_transaction)

let row = warehouse_delivery_transaction.find(x => x.kerry_status_name === 'CCC')
if (!row) {
  //let item = warehouse_delivery_transaction.find(x => x.kerry_status_name === 'BBB')    
  //if (item) {
  warehouse_delivery_transaction.splice(warehouse_delivery_transaction.length - 1, 0, {
    code: 'cc',
    kerry_status_name: 'CCC',
    location: '',
    status_date: 'cc'
  })
  //}
}

console.log('After: ', warehouse_delivery_transaction)
```